# How can I have a maven-like dependency management with SBT?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, databricks, dependency-management

I'm looking for a way to have a centralized way to handle my dependencies.

**The context**

I'm working with Databricks and their spark clusters have predefined versions of some libraries and each time I have a project I need to repeat those dependencies, with their version, and mark them as provided. Also each time the Databricks runtime gets updated we get new versions and I need to go dig in there to find the proper dependencies and update my projects. I'm not the only one working on those projects so it's not unusual to find a project where versions are not consistent. It's usually not an issue but it can be when major updates occur.

**What I tried to do**

We have this utils project that has a few helpers that are common to our various jobs. I wanted to use this project as a version provider for those libs. However those libs are marked as provided or optional so they are not provided as a transitive dependency of the project.

**What I'd like to do**

I would like to be able to have a some kind of dependency management in SBT. For instance something like a `bom` I could import or a `parent` project I could reference like I do with my spring-boot projects.

**How can I have some kind of dependency management provided from an external project in SBT ?**

Thanks

Comment: You can have a simple `CommonDependencies.scala` file that lists those and then you can copy-paste it from project to project. If you want something more robust and automated you can make that into a little **sbt** plugin.

Comment: As Luis said, you could make your own SBT plugin. Or you may use the SBT BOM plugin, it's relatively new but it should provide a similar experience as what you'd have with Maven: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sbt-bom

Comment: The sbt bom plugin seems a bit complex though to put in place in every project. A lot of specific lines. I'm not sure I want to depend that much on something custom TBH Gaël.

I'm curious however about having a centralized `CommonDependencies.scala` if that's what you mean Luis. How would I go about creating an sbt plugin that declares only those versions in a Scala `object` that I would be able to import and use ?